# product not adding to cart on localhost

Tags: opencart-3

I am using opencart 3.0.

my site is working on live server, now I download it on localhost everything is fine but when I click on add to cart button it give me error of too many redirects. my URLs are seo friendly, i am very new to opencart, and want some customization site.

image
[image]

```
I am using journal theme.
```

thank you in advance.

Comment: Does your local server support SEO URLs?

Comment: @K.B. yes other url are working only add to cart request is not working

Comment: You should check what generate this /ba/ba/ba/ba/ba/ba/ba. try to delete all cache files in your storage/cache directory.

Comment: @K.B. I have deleted all the file from cache already but it is not working..